# gantt chart not load in ui view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, gantt-chart

I'm using ui-router in my project. I need to use gantt chart. I refered this link http://rawgit.com/angular-gantt/angular-gantt/master/demo/dist/index.html.

I got this error

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$compile/ctreq?p0=gantt&p1=ganttTable
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:6:417
    at D (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:56:98)
    at A (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:59:241)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:299)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:316)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:316)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:316)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:316)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:316) <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you have the relevant dependencies and correct organization of the directives in the view: http://plnkr.co/edit/XYYkD8tf5b2LQs5kL5nx?p=info

This error can occur if a directive uses "require" in it's definition but the required controller can't be found (which means some directive on a parent or sibling it expected didn't exist)

HTML

```
<div gantt data="data">
    <!-- <gantt-table columns="['model.name']"></gantt-table> -->
    <gantt-tree></gantt-tree>
    <gantt-groups></gantt-groups>
    <gantt-tooltips></gantt-tooltips>
    <gantt-bounds></gantt-bounds>
    <gantt-progress></gantt-progress>
    <gantt-sortable></gantt-sortable>
    <gantt-movable></gantt-movable>
    <gantt-draw-task></gantt-draw-task>
    <gantt-resize-sensor></gantt-resize-sensor>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plnkrGanttStable',
['gantt',
'gantt.sortable',
'gantt.movable',
'gantt.drawtask',
'gantt.tooltips',
'gantt.bounds',
'gantt.progress',
'gantt.table',
'gantt.tree',
'gantt.groups',
'gantt.resizeSensor'
]);
```

See the error URL in the stacktrace for some details https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=gantt&p1=ganttTable%20at%20Error%20(native)

Comment: If you are this message accept the answer so others who find your question see it's resolved and I get my treasured points :)